# How to parse search api odata json result in C#

Tags: c#, json, odata, sharepoint-2013

I'm using this search query

```
string siteUrl = "<site>";
string  queryText ="Path:\"pathTosearch/*\" IsDocument:1";
string rowlimit = "10";
string sortExpression = "Write:descending";
string uriTempale = "{0}_api/search/query?querytext='{1}'&rowlimit={2}&sortlist='{3}'";
```

and i call it with httpwebrequest i need to parse the result to C# object, is there a direct way to achieve that or i have to use

```
dynamic dynObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using json.net you can use generics to deserialize and avooid using dynamic [see example here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm)